# Assigned icon to Windows 10 folder doesn't show

Tags: windows-10, icons

I created desktop.ini files for a number of folders programmatically, like folders having "picture" in it should show a camera icon. The desktop.ini files look like this:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=D:\Images\Icons\camera.ico,0
```

and I made the files system and hidden. And checked that the .ico file exists.

Yet none of the icons show. I tried rebuilding the icon cache, but got "access denied" responses when I tried to delete the cache DB (and yes, I cancelled the Explorer task first).
Anyhoo, rebuilding the cache shouldn't be necessary, since assigning an icon manually through properties and customize does work.

Do I have to send a notification message to the OS when I create the desktop.ini files? Or what else is different between assigning the icon manually or programmatically?

**edit**
To clarify, by "programmatically" I mean an executable (.exe), not a PowerShell or other script. The distinction may be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

For **Explorer** to process the ***desktop.ini*** file, the folder must have its **Read-only** or **System** attribute set.

You can use the **attrib** command from a **Command Promp**t or **PowerShell**:

```
attrib +r "c:\myfolder"
```

In **PowerShell**:

```
(get-item "c:\myfolder").Attributes += 'Readonly'
```

Check the folder's attributes by adding the **Attributes** column to a **Details** view:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Keith. Don't you mean readonly **and** system? I set the system attribute, like I said in OP. The readonly attribute is often mentioned, though I don't think it matters. In any case it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: The OP says you set the _file's_ attributes. You need to set the _folder's_ attributes. Add the 'Attributes' column to a Details view of your User folder and note that all the folders with custom icons have the **R** attribute set.

Comment: Though the desktop.ini files created by the system have _both_ their **Hidden** & **System** attributes set, neither is necessary for the file to be processed. But the _folder_ must have _either_ its **Read-only** or **System** attribute set.

Comment: OK, I tried that, but it doesn't help either. I'll clarify in OP that I'm actually talking about _programmatically_ assigning the icon (as in an .exe file), not through _scripting_. I have a hunch that the distinction matters. Thanks again, anyway.

Comment: Are you restarting Explorer or broadcasting an update message?

Comment: I restarted Explorer, and even rebooted my PC. No avail. My guess is that I indeed have to broadcast a message, though I don't know which one that should be. That's basically the gist of my question.

Comment: If you're restarting/rebooting, broadcasting a message is unnecessary. Are you able to assign your .ico file to a folder using the **Customize** tab in its **Properties** dialog? Do your standard user shell folders (Documents, Music, etc.) display their custom icons?